# How to get text to be Bold, Blue, Size 16, and a specific font with python-docx?

Tags: python, colors, automation, formatting, python-docx

I am trying to get python-docx to spit out some of my text as size 16 blue and bolded Calibri. I see how to do it separately, but it generates the same words repeated in each different format. How do I get it to apply all my formatting to just one piece of text?

Below is what I currently have.

```
    font.name='Calibri'
    document.add_paragraph().add_run('Area: '+str(df.loc[df['Subject']==i,'Area'].iloc[0])).bold=True
    document.add_paragraph().add_run('Area: '+str(df.loc[df['Subject']==i,'Area'].iloc[0])).font.color.rgb = RGBColor(79, 129, 189)
    document.add_paragraph().add_run('Area: '+str(df.loc[df['Subject']==i,'Area'].iloc[0])).font.size=16
```

At the moment it doesn't apply the font and produces the following formatting of Text

**Text**

Text (in Blue)

Text (Size 16)

I want it to produce 'Text' once Bolded, Blue, Size 16, and Calibri. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run(
    'Area: '+str(df.loc[df['Subject']==i,'Area'].iloc[0])
)
run.bold=True
run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(79, 129, 189)
run.font.name = 'Calibri'
run.font.size=16
```

Your initial form, just adding one of the properties onto the end of the `.add_run()` call, can be handy if you're only setting a single property and don't need the run reference afterward. But the more general method is to capture the `Run` object returned by `.add_run()` and then apply whatever property settings you need to it.

Comment: ran this and now the text doesn't appear. does adding this mean you have to change the document.save() ?